# MSSQL and Win Server issues - my problem, or host's?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I've been developing against SQL Server 2005 and my host-to-be supports windows server 2008. I understand that there are known issues with this combination, as well as resolutions/work-arounds. My question is, are these resolutions/workarounds something I have to look into, or is that something the webhost has to look into? I.e. Are the problems developer side, or simply for the hosts? (Examples [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936302))

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the developer you should not have to worry about any of the problems in that article, they are for the host to deal with as installation issues.  There are other things that you'll need to take into consideration as the developer, but those would be mostly limited to [**features that were discontinued in SQL 2008**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx) and are mostly administrator features anyway.  You'll probably also want to have a look at the [**features that will be deprecated in future versions of SQL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx).

Comment: Except for item 1, the syntax of the connection string when SQL is in a failover cluster, as I pointed out in my answer. That would be something for him, as developer, to handle.

Comment: @mfinni: Yep, +1'ed your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, reading that link, here's my take on the problem numbers.

1. Are you installing in a failover cluster? If not, no issue. If you are, then apply the workaround in your client code as it says. It's on you.
2. Also a failover issue. The fix is to apply SQL 2005 SP2. Who is responsible for that? If the provider is responsible for installing and configuring SQL in the first place, then I would argue it is with them. If they're just giving you a Windows box without SQL and you're installing it, then I think it's up to you.
3. Fix for problem 3 is also to apply SQL 2005 SP2, same as above.
4. Are you installing on an RODC? That would be weird, so don't do that. It sounds like it's not supported, so that's neither your provider or you.
5. Same as Problem 2 and 3 - apply SQL 2005 SP2.